# Parametrized conditional formatting

Tags: function, formatting, conditional-statements, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to dynamically set the Style of a row in Calc.

After giving up using a **macro** (see [Changing cell background color in LibreOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089051/changing-cell-background-color-in-libreoffice)), I tried with **Conditional Formatting** rules (*Format --> Conditional Formatting*).

I would like to set a parametrized `Range`, so that the conditional formula is applied separately for each row.

I tried using the ADDRESS function to express ranges:

```
A1:C6    --->   ADDRESS(1,1):ADDRESS(6,3)
```

But that doesn't work.
This reduces down to testing single cell functions, for instance:

```
    .------------------- -- -
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D
.----------------------- -- -
| 1 | aaa | bbb | ccc | 
.--------------------- -- -

[ok] =ADDRESS(1,3)
  \____$C$1

[ok] =CELL("contents", C1)
  \____ccc

[error] =CELL("contents", ADDRESS(1,3))
   \____#REF!
```

As you see, the last function gives a `#REF!` error (instead of `ccc`).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**ADDRESS**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#ADDRESS) returns the reference *as text*. [**CELL**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#CELL) expects a *reference*. So you need to translate the reference string using [**INDIRECT**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT):

> =CELL("CONTENTS", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,3)))

Comment: Thanks @tohuwawohu. Now I can parametrize my conditional formatting applying a style "by-row" in my *formula* like: `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), 7)) = 0`.